# error fitting function to data using nls

Tags: r, regression, nls, non-linear-regression, model-fitting

I have some issue using `nls()` to estimate parameters. I have a following set of functions to explain some data in hand:

```
funk1 <- function(a,x) { x^2*exp(-(l*(1-exp(-r*a))/r)) }

funk2 <- function(x) { sapply(x, function (s)
{ integrate(funk1, lower = 0, upper = s, x=s)$value }) }
```

I am trying to fit `funk2` to `y`:

```
y <- sort(runif(100, 0, 10^8))
```

When I use `nls()`:

```
nls(y ~ funk2(z1$days.post.bmt), data= z1, start=list(l=0.02, r=0.002), trace=T)
```

it shows me following error:

> Error in f(x, ...) : object 'l' not found

Isn't the whole point of `nls()` to substitute different values for parameters `l` and `r` from parameter space to fit the function by minimizing *SSR* and give the parameter estimates? why it needs value of `l` for it to work? I am definitely missing something big here. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass parameters `l` and `r` as function arguments of `funk1` and `funk2`.

```
funk1 <- function(a,x,l,r) {
  x^2*exp(-(l*(1-exp(-r*a))/r))
  }

funk2 <- function(x,l,r) {
  sapply(x, function (s) {
              integrate(funk1, lower = 0, upper = s, x=s, l=l, r=r)$value
              })
  }
```

I will generate some data to test:

```
z <- data.frame(days.post.bmt = 1:100,
                y = funk2(1:100, l = 1, r = 1) + rpois(100, 1:100))

nls(y ~ funk2(days.post.bmt,l,r), data = z, start = list(l = 0.5, r = 0.5))

#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: y ~ funk2(days.post.bmt, l, r)
#   data: z
#     l      r 
#0.9405 0.9400 
# residual sum-of-squares: 6709

#Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.354e-07
```

As a counter example, consider:

```
bad_funk1 <- function(a,x) {
  x^2*exp(-(l*(1-exp(-r*a))/r))
  }

bad_funk2 <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function (s) {
              integrate(funk1, lower = 0, upper = s, x=s)$value
              })
  }

nls(y ~ bad_funk2(days.post.bmt), data = z, start = list(l = 0.5, r = 0.5))
# Error in f(x, ...) (from #2) : argument "l" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! you pretty much answered most of my r related problems. out of curiosity, may I know what do you do?

Comment: Oh, that's exciting! I am venturing into the world of statistics slowly now and I find it pretty confusing. Wish you luck for thesis writing - coming from a person who has recently gone through the world's most boring task himself! :)

Comment: Hey I had another query which I have posted as a question. It relates with MLE and using optim to extimate parameters. If you have some time and are excited enough to look at the issue please find it here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/38486139/6533048  Hope, I am not imposing.