# Error in using optim to maximise the likelihood in r

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, non-linear-regression, mle

So, I have these functions:

```
funk1 <- function(a,x,l,r) {
x^2*exp(-(l*(1-exp(-r*a))/r))}

funk2 <- function(x,l,r) {
sapply(x, function (s) {
integrate(funk1, lower = 0, upper = s, x=s, l=l, r=r)$value })}
```

which are used to explain the data y in,

```
z <- data.frame(ts = 1:100,
            y = funk2(1:100, l = 1, r = 1) + rpois(100, 1:100))
```

I wish to use optim to maximise the likelihood, so I defined a likelihood function:

```
LL_funk <- function(l,r) { 
n=nrow(z)
R = sum((funk2(ts,l,r) - y)^2)
logl = -((n/2)*log(R))
return(-logl)
}
```

and I tried to fit using optim

```
fit <- optim(par=c(0.5,0.5), fn= LL_funk, method="Nelder-Mead")
```

But I get an error:

```
 Error in integrate(funk1, lower = 0, upper = s, x = s, l = l, r = r) : 
 a limit is missing
```

I am not sure why? I could run nls fitting funk2(x,l,r) to y

```
nls(y ~ funk2(ts,l,r), data = z, start = list(l = 0.5, r = 0.5))
```

That means funk2 is working. I guess its the problem with LL function that I have designed, which I cant figure out!! Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup! There were two problems with your function. This worked for me:

```
LL_funk <- function(params) { 
  n=nrow(z)
  l = params[1]
  r = params[2]
  R = sum((funk2(z$ts,l,r) - z$y)^2)
  logl = -((n/2)*log(R))
  return(-logl)
}
```

Previous issues:

- `LL_funk` only takes 1 argument, which is the vector of parameters.
- In LHS of the assignment of `R`, `ts` and `y` were not actually referring to columns in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Did not  know that LL function takes only one argument. second issue was the typo error.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Yes I should start doing that, very carefully. Thanks!